# I lost all my contacts on Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s, data-recovery

Yesterday I lost all the contacts on my GT-I9000. Nothing strange happened, there was no warning, suddenly they were just.. gone. This is the second time this happens. Is there any method to get the lost contacts back?

Comment: See my answer on a similar SMS question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/33896/15713). In short: It might have been due to bad flash cells on your device. To mitigate this in the future: Use Google's contact sync service to avoid such situations. It's automatic and you can forget about single point of failures (phone stolen/broken, buggy software) from then on.

Comment: Cheers! I'm not phone/computer savvy so I've no idea what bad flash cells are. Not even when I read your answer to the SMS question.
Thank the gods I have a backup file, although it's couple of months old. Going to installa that SMS Backup + now, thank you so much for help!

Comment: Good to know you got at least partial data back! I meant the storage of your phone with *flash cells*, this type of storage doesn't last forever and parts of it may die after it has been written a number of times (10k or so). So do backups or sync your address book with google.

Comment: Now how do I do that sync with google? I've tried but don't seem to able to accomplish anything..

Comment: It seems like we don't have a question of the type "How can I sync my contacts with google?". @KyöstiKantee Feel free to ask this question. Contacts sync is a nice feature of Google enabled Android phones, although it comes with the familiar privacy concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have contacts on your Google account? If yes, re-login, and load from Google.